# AIX : (non-root) SU to (non-root) secondary account WITHOUT secondary account password

Tags: aix, su

For AIX (7.1 to be specific):  Are there configuration changes that can be made to permit user1 to su to user2  WITHOUT KNOWLEDGE of the user2's password?

user1) su - user2

Due to immutable requirements (grr), (non-root) admins are required by a vendors' procedure to execute scripts as the given user account which has escalated privilege and is deeply embedded into the core of the program.

It is desired to discontinue the use of a shared password.  For tracking purposes, current procedure is for the admins to log in with their own account, and then su to the secondary account with the shared password for the account.  (The secondary account is disabled for direct login presently).

Answer (score 0):

Your post didn't reference "sudo" but it's a basic configuration for sudo.